# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool with pandas

Tags: pandas, boolean, conditional-statements

I am trying to store the following conditional in a variable excel_filtered
`excel_filtered = excel[excel['prowess_compustat_h1b'] == 1] | excel['compustat_h1b'] == 1`

but I get the following error

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'`

**EDIT**

It was a simple syntax error, missing a bracket at the end. Correct answer is the following:

```
excel_filtered = excel[excel['prowess_compustat_h1b'] == 1] | excel['compustat_h1b'] == 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have a square bracket in the wrong place. That, and it's always best practice to use parentheses when evaluating multiple boolean criteria.

```
excel_filtered = excel[(excel['prowess_compustat_h1b'] == 1) | (excel['compustat_h1b'] == 1)]
```

Also for these types of operations, I find that the `query` method can increase readability:

```
excel_filtered = excel.query("(prowess_compustat_h1b == 1) | (compustat_h1b == 1)"
```